# Encountering GPG Errors with Ubuntu Repositories in GitLab CI/CD Pipeline

Tags: docker, ubuntu, gitlab

I'm currently working on a project where the CI/CD pipeline is set up in GitLab using Docker with an `ubuntu` image. It also worked fine for the last month. However, it does not work anymore in the past few days. I've run into a problem during the `apt-get update` step, where it fails due to GPG errors related to the Ubuntu repositories. Here is the relevant part of my `.gitlab-ci.yml` file:

```
manage-releases:
  stage: manage-releases
  needs:
    - job: release_job
  image: ubuntu # Also tried with ubuntu:latest or specific version numbers, didn't change anything
  before_script:
    - apt-get clean # I already added this because I read that this would solve the issue. But it didn't.
    - apt-get -qq update
    - apt-get install -y jq curl
  script:
    - sh manage_releases.sh # Execute a script that requires jq package
```

The error I'm encountering is the following:

```
...
$ apt-get clean
$ apt-get -qq update
W: GPG error: http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease: At least one invalid signature was encountered.
E: The repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease' is not signed.
W: GPG error: http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease: At least one invalid signature was encountered.
E: The repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease' is not signed.
W: GPG error: http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease: At least one invalid signature was encountered.
E: The repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease' is not signed.
W: GPG error: http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease: At least one invalid signature was encountered.
E: The repository 'http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease' is not signed.
```

Any insights or suggestions on how to troubleshoot and resolve these errors would be greatly appreciated! Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

This error indicates that the GPG key signatures for the Ubuntu repositories are not valid/trusted on your system.

To fix it, you need to update the list of trusted GPG keys. Run the following commands:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install debian-archive-keyring ubuntu-keyring
```

This will download and install the latest trusted keys.

Then try running `apt update` or `apt-get update` again. The repositories should now validate properly without errors.

Some things to note:

- The keys may have been changed by Ubuntu due to security or other reasons, which causes your cached keys to be invalid
- Your system clock could be inaccurate, causing signature validation to fail
- You may have manually removed or altered the keyring files previously

Resetting the keyring as shown above should resolve the issue in most cases by downloading fresh trusted keys from the key servers.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! How do I run the sudo commands? Do I just put them in the `before_script`, or is there another way?

Comment: You can run these commands before executing scripts or you can add these commands in the beginning of script.